# Are kangaroos dangerous?

Tags: animals, australia

When I first saw a man get kicked by a kangaroo, I said "nope to Australia" because that is mainly where kangaroos are. Then, I looked on google and it said kangaroos are not dangerous. So now I'm not so worried about kangaroos.

Comment: Nothing is without danger....

Comment: Will a kangaroo that you are harassing kick you?  Absolutely yes.  Will a kangaroo that sees you from a distance run over just for the pleasure of kicking you?  No, that would be absurd.  Aside from that, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/14533/9109

Comment: @cobaltduck https://mashable.com/video/paraglider-attacked-kangaroo-australia/